# When using the following regexp query, how can I escape the special character in the keyword?

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

When using the following regexp query, how can I escape the special character (') in the keyword? I can't seem to find where to place the \' sequence.

```
WITH ["Freda's"] AS keywords
WITH REDUCE(s = [], x IN keywords | s + ('(?i).*' + x + '.*')) AS regexps
MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE all(x IN regexps WHERE p.name =~ x)
RETURN p
```

Comment: It doesn't appear so, but if that were the solution where would that be placed in the query?

Comment: Could you please precise what is wrong with the code? What is the input and what is expected output? Also, if it is Java, I think you can replace `'` with `\u0022`.

Comment: Sure. I have product names that are arrays. Some of the values in the arrays may contain special characters like ('). When I enter the product name as a keyword as in the above query it does not return a result if the name contains a special character. I'm only able to query product names that do not have a special character like ('). So, I am wondering how can I escape the special character or what may be the appropriate syntax so that I can query a product name that contains a special character, specifically (')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cypher query does work as written, so this is likely an issue with how you are using your programming language to generate the strings in the `WITH` clause.

Practically speaking, you should not be passing the `keywords` array in the way you have shown, anyway. A more performant and secure approach (which may also help to work around your issue) would be to pass the array as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters). The parameter value would just be a native array in whatever language you are using.

If you passed the `keywords` array as a parameter, your query would be:

```
WITH REDUCE(s = [], x IN {keywords} | s + ('(?i).*' + x + '.*')) AS regexps
MATCH (p:Product)
WHERE ALL(x IN regexps WHERE p.name =~ x)
RETURN p;
```

*By the way, are you sure you want to use `ALL()` instead of `ANY()`?*

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I'm sure about ALL(). My issue is if I have a product name ["fredas"] I can get that returned just fine, but if I have the product name ["freda's"] I can not get it returned at all. This is my issue.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What language are you using, and how are you using it to generate the Cypher code that you are attempting to execute? You need to make sure that you generate the keyword strings properly, and use parameters instead of the `WITH` clause.

Comment: JSON, however I am attempting the query in the neo4j browser. I know we aren't supposed to ask questions within a question, but how can I use a parameter instead of the WITH clause?